# Apply linear combinations on a number n times, for non-integer values of n.

Tags: calculus, integration

To simplify my question I will create a new notation just for us (to make my actual question less confusing):
$x £ (^a_1) = ax + b$

Now, sometimes in math, you can apply an operation multiple times to a value, such as:
`0 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2`, which can be expressed simply as `2 * 4` or, if you're feeling wild, $\sum_1^42$.

What happens with products also, hence the x<sup>y</sup> notation for exponents (or $\prod_1^yx$, but that's too much wildness for me).

Now, the sigma and pi notations can be expanded, but they can only express sums and products that happen an integer number of times, while x<sup>y</sup> is continuous; works for values like $16^{0.5}=4$.

I suspect the answer to this lies within calculus, integrals or differentiation (this problem is how I narrowed down a much bigger problem that involved slopes), but anyways *how can I express a series of linear combinations in a way that's continuous?*

$(1 £ (^a_1)) £ (^a_1) ...$ n times, even for $n \not\in Z$.

---

EDIT 1:

If instead of using my non-existing notation and defining a linear combination as a function f(x) = ax + b, I can apply this function to itself t times (ITERATION), expanding to find a common law.

$f(x) = ax + b$

$f^2(x) = a^2x + ab + b$

$f^3(x) = a^3x + a^2b + ab + b$

so

$f^t(x) = a^tx + b (a^{t-1} + a^{t-2} + ... + a^0)$

And this only went in circles, but, apparently, a linear combination with "1" as its linear coefficient can be easily describable with a finite sum of decaying powers!

The previous term multiplied by b can be isolated and rewritten as such:

$(a^{t-1} + a^{t-2} + ... + a^0) = 1 £ (^a_1) £ ...$ t-1 times.

So

$a^x + a^{x-1} + a^{x-2} + ... + a^{0} = 1 \underbrace{£ (^a_1) £ (^a_1)}_{x \text( times)}$

My previous iteration of linear combinations then equals to some terms and a sum of increasing powers.

$a^tx + b\sum_{i=0}^x2^i = 1 \underbrace{£ (^a_b) £ (^a_b)}_{t \text( times)}$

What I want is the way to *calculate the finite sum of powers of some number as in $\sum_{i=0}^xa^i$ for non-integer values of x (continuously)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *general* question seems to be: Given a function $f$, if you know the values of $f(n)$ for integer $n$, how do you determine what $f(x)$ is when $x$ is not an integer?

The answer is that without knowing something more about the function $f$, you can't. There are uncountably many functions $g$ that agree with $f$ at every integer, but vary wildly in values between integers. In order for $f$ to be uniquely determined, we have to know more about it. In the example you gave, we can define $f(x) = a^x$ for non-integer $x$ because there are a couple of properties we want it to obey:

- From the definition of $a^n$ for integer $n$, you can show $a^{mn} = (a^m)^n$. We want this property to hold more generally: $a^{xy} = (a^x)^y$.
- Also, when $a > 1$, if $n < m$, then $a^n < a^m$ (with the reverse for $a < 1$). We also want this property to hold for general $x$.

These two properties only allow one extension of $f(x) = a^x$ from integer to non-integer $x$. The first allows you to extend $f$ to rational numbers. And because rational numbers are dense (between any two real numbers, there is a rational number), the second means that the value of $f(x)$ for irrational $x$ is trapped by $f(r)$ for rational $r$ near $x$ to be a single choice (this entrapment requires a certain behavior of $f$ on its rational values, but it is not too hard to show that behavior is true).

It is this additional knowledge about $a^x$ that allows us to define $x$ for non-integer values. And similarly for other functions originally defined for integers only. Without additional conditions, there are too many possibilities to be able to define the function.

---

However, for your particular example, it is not that hard to come up with a credible extension. Your notation is ... not the best. Mathematics has long dealt with problems like this, and has standard ways of denoting them. In your case, just define the function $$g(x) = ax+b$$
If you really want to make the dependence of $g$ on $a, b$ explicit, you could use the notation $$g_{a,b}(x)$$ instead, but I think we can just keep in mind that $g$ also depends on these two variables. What you are doing is called "iteration" - the repeated application of the function $g$: $g(x), g(g(x)), g(g(g(x))), ...$. The most common notation for this is $$g^n(x) = \underbrace{g(g(g(...g(}_{n\text{ times}}x)...)))$$
(Be aware though that the same notation is commonly used for ordinary exponentiation: $f^n(x) = (f(x))^n$. You have to determine which meaning is intended by context.)

It isn't too hard to expand the iterations of $g$:

- $g^1(x) = g(x) = ax +b$
- $g^2(x) = g(g^1(x)) = a(ax + b) + b = a^2x + ab + b = a^2x + (a + 1)b$
- $g^3(x) = g(g^2(x)) = a(a^2x + (a + 1)b) + b = a^3x + (a^2 + a + 1)b$
- ...
- $g^n(x) = a^nx + (a^{n-1} + a^{n-2} + \ldots + a + 1)b$

Now that sum $a^{n-1} + a^{n-2} + \ldots + a + 1$ is well-known. If you multiply it by $a - 1$, it "telescopes". The middle terms all cancel out:
$$(a - 1)(a^{n-1} + a^{n-2} + \ldots + a + 1) = a^n - 1$$
or
$$a^{n-1} + a^{n-2} + \ldots + a + 1 = \dfrac {a^n -1}{a-1}$$

If you define $f(x,n) = g^n(x)$, then $$f(x,n) = a^nx + \dfrac{a^n-1}{a-1}b$$

From which an obvious extension to non-integer values appears:
$$f(x, y) = a^yx + \dfrac{a^y-1}{a-1}b$$
Again, this is not the only extension, but it is probably the best behaved.

Comment: My question was precisely for when f(x) is a linear combination, I did this precisely to expand. In fact you repeated the same steps as I did, while I got stuck on the very last. It clearly solves my problem with continuity, but, so I can search and learn this tool, where is this sum $a^{n−1}+a^{n−2}+…+a+1$ known from; how come I can multiply it by (a - 1) and keeping both sides equal?

Comment: Also, I understand that math has its cannon notations, when you overhead my question and repeat the same steps I did with different variable names it can be frustrating and confusing also.

Comment: Ok, it's a geometric series.

Comment: Continuity is not enough to get you from integer values to all real values. It is only useful once you know the function values on a dense set. As for "how come I can multiply it by $(a-1)$ and keep both sides equal?" I have to ask what "sides" you are refering to? $a^{n-1} + \ldots + 1$ is an expression, not an equation. Try it. Multiply it by $a-1$ yourself and see that it reduces to $a^n -1$. As your other comment, I was writing this post before you made your "Edit 1", and did not see it. I am not psychic and cannot know what notations and addendums you are going to make in the future.

Comment: Well, it is an expression and not an equation. The term $a^{n−1}+…+1$ is an expression. It is, however, inserted on a function right before that paragraph (gn(x)). It has an equal sign, so it must mean that the left and the right term are equal. Multiplying $a^{n−1}+ … +1$ by $(a - 1)$ does reduce to $a^n - 1$, yes, but isn't this going to change the value of the expression and, by extension, the value of the right term on the previous equation? Also, not everyone has psychic powers anyways.

Comment: I never multiplied the expression for $g_n(x)$ by anything, on either side of it. I strongly suggest you try reading ahead *just one more line* to see what it is that I *actually did* with this calculation instead of accusing me of something I never did. The very next equation gives an alternate expression for $a^{n-1} + \ldots + 1$ that I did substitute into the expression for $g_n(x)$. But that is a direct substitution of equal for equal. It does not multiply by anything.